# Open source Sichuanese TTS (语音合成?)

Tags: topolect, software

There's a couple of iOS apps that support Sichuanese TTS (text-to-speech):

- 川话达人
- 语音合成助手

From what I can tell it's all from a company called [讯飞](http://dev.voicecloud.cn/msc/help.html), but I'm not totally sure.

Is there an open source Sichuanese TTS available?

Or

An offline Sichuanese TTS that doesn't need to download the audio each time?

Comment: An open source TTS, offline, and for a Chinese dialect used by only 8 percent of the total population? I'm not sure. Even open source TTS for standard Chinese is rare, if it exists.

Comment: Whether it can handle Sichuanese mainly depend on the data of the TTS, not the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about the company. It's full name is 科大讯飞. 科大is short for 中国科学技术大学(University of Science and Technology of China)，my Alma mater!--this company is founded by several alumni in cooperation with the university.

TTS is not difficult for 科大讯飞, and they put their effort more on speech-to-text engine. But they have open source packages for both TTS and STT, and a whole bunch of other cool stuff. Actually, they have been there at least since 2014. You could find them here (all-Chinese site): http://www.xfyun.cn/sdk/dispatcher Their TTS and STT support A LOT of dialects.

Alternatively, there is a Chinese TTS on Github: https://github.com/yantze/vim-tts  It also supports a lot of dialects, including Sichuanese.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such open-source Sichuanese TTS available so far.

Answer (score 0):

讯飞 (short for 科大讯飞) is a leading tech company in speech synthesis and recognition.  An [online-demo](http://www.xfyun.cn/default/online_demo) for Sichuanese TTS is demonstrated on their website. In addition, they have provided an offline [TTS SDK](http://www.xfyun.cn/sdk/dispatcher), you may have a try.